# Add type hints to function that accepts any iterable and returns zipped values

Tags: type-hinting, mypy, python-3.10

I have the following working code to solve [Advent of Code 2021 day 1](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/1) (requires Python 3.10 due to [itertools.pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)), but I am stuck on how to correctly add type hints.

```py
from itertools import pairwise, tee
from typing import Iterator, TypeVar, Tuple, Generator

_T_co = TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)

def tripletwise(iterable: Iterator[_T_co]) -> zip[Tuple[_T_co, _T_co, _T_co]]:
    """tripletwise('ABCDEFG') --> ABC BCD CDE DEF EFG"""
    a, b, c = tee(iterable, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return zip(a, b, c)


def sonar_sweep(sea_floor_depths: Generator[int, None, None], part: int = 1) -> int:
    if part == 1:
        return sum(b > a for a, b in pairwise(sea_floor_depths))
    return sonar_sweep((a + b + c for a, b, c in tripletwise(sea_floor_depths)), part=1)


def sea_floor_depths(report: str) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    return map(int, report.splitlines())


def main(part: int = 1) -> int:
    with open("2021/data/day01.txt") as f:
        report = f.read()
    return sonar_sweep(sea_floor_depths(report), part)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    report = """199
200
208
210
200
207
240
269
260
263"""
    assert sonar_sweep(sea_floor_depths(report), part=1) == 7
    assert sonar_sweep(sea_floor_depths(report), part=2) == 5
    assert list(tripletwise("ABCDEFG")) == [
        ("A", "B", "C"),
        ("B", "C", "D"),
        ("C", "D", "E"),
        ("D", "E", "F"),
        ("E", "F", "G"),
    ]
    assert list(tripletwise(sea_floor_depths(report))) == [
        (199, 200, 208),
        (200, 208, 210),
        (208, 210, 200),
        (210, 200, 207),
        (200, 207, 240),
        (207, 240, 269),
        (240, 269, 260),
        (269, 260, 263),
    ]

    print(main())
    print(main(part=2))
```

Currently, when I run mypy on this, I get:

```py
2021/day01.py:22: error: Incompatible return value type (got "map[int]", expected "Generator[int, None, None]")
2021/day01.py:44: error: Argument 1 to "tripletwise" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Iterator[<nothing>]"
```

I want to indicate with the type hints that `tripletwise()` can accept any iterable (for example both the string `"ABCDEFG"` or the output of `sea_floor_depths(report)`). I'm also unsure about the correct return type of `sea_floor_depths()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the first error, the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) builtin is only documented to return an iterator, so the most specific type hint that you can use is `Iterator[int]`. `Generator` is a subtype of `Iterator` that only arises when using generator expressions or generator functions, which your function does not.

For the second error, the issue is that `str`s are not themselves [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), but rather only [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), so the appropriate type hint would be `Iterable[_T_co]`.